# Will I get notifications for updates for packages in backport?

Tags: backport

If I install a package from the backports repository, will it get automatically updated with 'dist-upgrade' later on or should I follow it by myself and update it manually when new version is released in backports?

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the backport sources check marked in your "Software and Updates", and you have enabled "Automatically check for updates" for a fixed period of time, you will be notified of updates to the packages in the backport sources:

[image: screenshot of software and updates]

If you have your backport sources enabled but have set "Automatic check for updates" to "Never" you won't get notifications but can update using

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

on a terminal or using the "Software updater" package.

Otherwise, if you have not enabled the backport sources, you will neither get notifications nor updates to those packages.